# Anybody know where the "Convert Brush to Resource" button went in Expression Blend 3?

Tags: expression-blend

Does anyone know where they put the "plus brush" in Blend 3 so that you can copy a brush into the resources?

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/plusBrush.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/plusBrush.png)

## Answer:

Stumbled onto it an hour later:

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/answerbrush.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/answerbrush.png)

Comment: Yes, theres a lot of functionality tucked away in that little button (Property Peg).